# Converting JavaFX 1.x scripts to JavaFX 2 Java code

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, porting

Is there any tool to convert existing JavaFX 1.x applications to JavaFX 2.x Java code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No such tool currently exists publicly and it is unlikely that one will be created.

Oracle did create a prototype tool which was used in internal Oracle development, but they decided not to continue development on it.

Quotes from the JavaFX project lead Richard Bair (from the forum threads linked below):

> **Richard:**  I'm sorry to say we have no tool to help with the migration. Our
>   experience from migrating the JavaFX Library and samples is that there
>   wasn't really an easy solution -- even the migration assistant that
>   was written was very incomplete. Some folks found it very useful, but
>   I just did it by hand.
>
> **PDVieira:** Any chance you could send me the FxTranslator helper you've
>   created?
>
> **Richard:** Wish I could, but unfortunately we cannot send it along
>   (actually, I don't even have the code on hand, didn't write it (Eamonn
>   did) and it would need to get legal approve to open source it, and it
>   probably doesn't even compile or work anymore because the platform has
>   change significantly since last December).

You can refer to these forum threads which discuss this further:

- https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=9967190
- https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=10064115

Comment: The FX script language was far more expressive than Java, and things that were very simple in it (like binding a filtered version of one list to another) are quite difficult in JavaFX 2. Perhaps Visage will one day be able to restore the language to the platform.